Powershell command to update sharepoint not executing from excel button
within excel, i have a button with the following macro when i click it
Sub MigrateFile_Click()

 strCommand = "Powershell -File  ""C:\Test\migrate.ps1"""

  Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

  Set WshShellExec = WshShell.Exec(strCommand)

 

End Sub


the powershell script looks like
#Read the Excel Data and change path accordingly
$data = Import-Excel -Path "C:\Test\ExcelFile.xlsm" -Worksheet data
#Declare Site URL and List names
$SiteUrl = "https://consato.sharepoint.com/sites/Stage"
$UserName="username@cansato.com"
$Password = "password"
# Update with the internal name of the SharePoint list.
$ListName = "Documents"

#Initiate a connection to SharePoint site
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$Cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $UserName, $SecurePassword
 
#connect to sharepoint online site using powershell
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials $Cred



try {
    ForEach($record in $data) {
        Write-host "Adding record $($record.'Info')"

        Add-PnPFile -Path C:\Test\ExcelFile.xlsm -Folder "Data" -Values @{Title=$($record.'Info')}
    }
} catch {
    Write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -ForegroundColor Red
}



but the script never executes when pressing the button. The script works whenever i run it by itself within powershell. Anyone know what's missing?
